# Change local storage location in refinerycms for uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, dragonfly-gem

I'm using refinerycms 1.0.9 and I'd like to change the default location where dragonfly saves the files.

Here is my dragonfly.rb in config/initializers:

```
require 'dragonfly'

app = Dragonfly[:app_name]
app.datastore = Dragonfly::DataStorage::FileDataStore.new

app.datastore.configure do |d|
  d.root_path = '/Projects/images'
  d.server_root = '/Projects'
  d.store_meta = false
end
```

When I save the file I get the following error:

```
Dragonfly::Shell::CommandFailed (Command failed (identify '/var/folders/5t/mf86p8gx6bz94dzfb88xpvpr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120328-6943-1vbpa7u') with exit status 127):
```

**UPDATE**

I reinstalled imagemagick and that got rid of the error, however it is still saving the files to /system/images.  I tried overriding the Image model in refinery and added:

```
image_accessor :image do
   storage_path{ "/Projects/images/#{rand(100)}" }
end
```

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Models.html#Storage_options) from the author it looks like you want to set the `storage_path` option in your model(s):

```
storage_path{ "some/path/#{first_name}/#{rand(100)}" } # or whatever you want it to be
```

Comment: I added the below to my slideshow model

    `image_accessor :photo do`
        `storage_path{ "slideshow/#{rand(100)}" }`
    `end`

And I now get this error
undefined method `photo_uid' for #<Slideshow:0x007f8f54e16708>

Comment: Added a photo_uid column to my model and now I'm back to the original error.

Comment: Does your target folder exist? I have a vague recollection that it needs to exist (with appropriate permissions) before dragonfly can use it.